# 2-adic number of given integer

Tags: c++, binary

i am reading section about  A Binary Recursive Gcd Algorithm,where this definition  is given
let v_2(a) denotes the 2-adic valuation of a, i.e. the number of consecutive zeroes in the least signicant bits of the  binary representation of a ,so i am trying to  find v_2(a) here    is code for this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int total=0;
    int n,k;
    cout << "enter value n ";
    k=0;
    cin >> n;
    while(k!=1)
    {
        if (k==1)
        {
            break;
        }
        k=n%2;
        n>>=1;
        total++;

    }
    cout<<total<<"  "<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

when i enter number  12 (in binary it is 1100) it should give me number 2  but it  shows 3,what is wrong?please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're breaking out of the while too late, since you're running `total++` when `k==1` has been reached.

Move the `if (k==1)` block after the `k=n%2;` line.

Note: The `k` variable isn't actually necessary. You could simplify the loop to:

```
while((n%2)==0) {
  n>>=1;
  total++;
}
```